# Cannot read index directory created by lucene from a servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, lucene

I have been trying to implement a small retrieval system using Apache Lucene. The app works well when use console for i/o. But i want to make it a web baed app. I have already created and tested the index using simple a cosole based test program. My index is at "D:\index".  But as soon as call the same search method from within the Servlet it shoots tons of errors.

Here is my Search class:

```
    package indexer;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
    import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
    import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

    import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException;

    public class Search {
    String index = "D:\\index";
    IndexReader reader;
     IndexSearcher searcher;
    Analyzer analyzer;
    QueryParser parser;

    // :Post-Release-Update-Version.LUCENE_XY:

    public Search() throws IOException  {
        index = "D:\\index";
        // IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new
        // File(index)));
        reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(index)));
        searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9);
        parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_4_9, "title", analyzer);
    }

    public String[] searchIndex(String queryString) throws IOException,
            ParseException,
            org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException {

        String[] ids = new String[10];
        int i=0;
            System.out.println("searching for: " + queryString);
            Query query = parser.parse(queryString);
            TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 10);
            System.out.println("total hits: " + results.totalHits);
            ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
            for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) {
                Document doc = searcher.doc(hit.doc);
                System.out.printf( hit.score+"   "+ doc.get("id")+" ");
                ids[i]=doc.get("id");
                i++;
            }

        // searcher.close();
        return  ids;
    }
}
```

And Here is my Servlet from where I tried to call the Search.searchIndex(query) method

```
package SearcherServlets;

import indexer.Search;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException;


@WebServlet("/SearchWeb")
public class SearchWeb extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SearchWeb() {
        super();

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Search search = new Search();
        try {
            search.searchIndex("Android");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

And here are the exceptions

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Personal]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Personal]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 20 more

Jul 11, 2014 1:24:48 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [126] milliseconds.
Jul 11, 2014 1:24:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jul 11, 2014 1:24:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

I have not been able to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The fact you are running this from a servlet container isn't relevant. Read the exception, it is pretty obvious:

`NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/ParseException`

The above means the class is not in the classpath. Most likely, you forgot to add `lucene-queryparser-4.9.0.jar` to `WEB-INF/lib` of your .war file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem trying to run the HelloLucene.java file after adding the lucene-core-5.0.0 jar file to my project library in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2. Thus I had to navigate into the queryparser folder in the lucene-5.0.0 folder and individually add the lucene-queryparser-5.0.0.jar file to my project libraries using this [tutorial on lucenetutorial website](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)